# How to set values in helm_release

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

Good day!

I am trying to set values of the [NVIDIA helm chart](https://github.com/gardener/gpu-installer/blob/master/charts/nvidia-installer/values.yaml) using helm terraform provider but I am not able to define the name of the variable correctly, some of the `.tf file` looks like the below:

```
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.driverVersion"
value = "${var.driverVersion}"
}
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.tag"
value = "${var.tag}"
}
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].key[0]"
value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityKey}"
}
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].operator[1]"
value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityOperator}"
}
```

Example of defining the values:

```
variable "driverVersion" {default = 440.31}
variable "tag" {default = "ae3f1b937f784b9e0d18f9dd03b67829381799c9" }
variable "nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityKey" {default = "gpu"}
variable "nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityOperator" {default = "In"}
variable "nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityValues" {default = "nvidia-tesla-t4"}
```

But when applying, I got the below issue:

```
1 error occurred:
* module.bocr-applications.helm_release.nvidia-gpu-installer: 1 error occurred:
* helm_release.nvidia-gpu-installer: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = release gpu-installer 
failed: DaemonSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a DaemonSet: v1.DaemonSet.Spec: 
v1.DaemonSetSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Affinity: 
v1.Affinity.NodeAffinity: v1.NodeAffinity.RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: 
v1.NodeSelector.NodeSelectorTerms: []v1.NodeSelectorTerm: 
v1.NodeSelectorTerm.MatchExpressions: []v1.NodeSelectorRequirement: 
v1.NodeSelectorRequirement.Key: ReadString: expects " or n, but found [, error found in #10 
byte of ...|:[{"key":["gpu",null|..., bigger context ...|"nodeSelectorTerms": 
[{"matchExpressions":[{"key":["gpu",null,"nvidia-tesla-t4"],"operator":[null,"In|...
```

Can Someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the above issue is due to bad overwriting of `key`, `operator` and `values` in values.yaml file.
helm release set array for the below example:

```
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.tag"
value = "${var.tag}"
}
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].key[0]"
value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityKey}"
}
set {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].operator[1]"
value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityOperator}"
}
```

should be defined as below:

```
set_string {
name  = "nvidiaInstaller.tag"
value = "${var.tag}"
}

set {
name  ="nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].key"
value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityKey}"
}
set {
name  ="nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].operator"
  value = "${var.nvidiaInstallerNodeAffinityOperator}"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That error could be a handful of things, a character that is non-ascii, null, or a bad indentation.

- Verify that you have no extra characters at the end of any given values.
- Do a `helm template` and verify that all fields have non null values rendered on the output.
- When you do a `helm template` verify that your blocks are aligned, I had an error liked the one you posted where my blocks weren't aligned and/or was using spaces/tabs and it tirggered that error

Comment: thanks, but the issue is when overwriting `nodeAffinity: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: nodeSelectorTerms: - matchExpressions: - key: gpu ` with  `name  = "nvidiaInstaller.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].operator[1]"`  I m not sure how to overwrite it correctly...

Comment: what does helm template render?

Comment: no issues, listed the template, so the problem is something with overwriting

Comment: You are gonna have to post some code and concrete examples / commands I fail to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suppose, I have solved my issue, please see proposed solution, if you see the question´s description needs to be adjusted, please help to correct it as well :)